# How do you add an email recipient in form builder in Odoo 13?

Tags: odoo, odoo-13

By default there should be a Send Email Action in the Form Parameter but there seems to be none. In some tutorials you can see this in the style tab where you can add a recipient but they style tab itself doesn't display—it's only Block and Options on my screen when I edit it directly. My goal is to have the user have an option who'll be the recipient OR have a default recipient instead. Would really appreciate the help or any resources explaining this

Answer (score 0):

In footer of all forms having a option as "add followers" and "add channels". You can set default recipients by adding them as a followers. Whenever you send  email, your followers will receive the email.